# Sencha Touch 2 how it relates to my knowledge of html5/javascript web development

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch-2

So Ive been learning HTML5 and javascript(including all the other stuff that goes with these two), and now my managers at my internship are asking me to use Sencha Touch 2. What I have found is that everything I have learned is almost irrelevant. I feel like the way things are done in Sencha Touch 2 are almost completely different from web development using html5/javascript...the only thing common is a tad bit of html and css. Am i correct or am i wrong? I feel like unsatisfied knowing i spent the last few weeks getting bettter at javascript/html5 to learn that it is not useful for sencha touch 2. I have not dwelled to deep yet into Sencha Touch, but that is how i feel so far

Comment: You **must** learn the underlying languages first, otherwise you are a slave to the library/framework/whatever that you've learned. They are the common thread to all web development and are essential to becoming a good developer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like most of the Sencha controls/widgets are configured using javascript code, and that the whole framework is built upon javascript. I wouldnt say that javascript is not usefull, quite the opposite. But you will probably feel that you are using the framework itself more that pure javascript.

It is the same with JQuery. It is basically just a framework built in and for javascript, but using it might feel like something else entirely.

One thing that is good to remember is that the better you know the language, the easier it will be to learn and to use the framework that utilizes it. And invariably you will have to knit the framework into webpages or applications, so you will have to use javascript and HTML5 for that as well.

Comment: alright, thanks a lot i appreciate the feed back, its just so disappointing -_- i was beginning to enjoy html5/js/jquery lol